# Does digits string belong to Json?

Tags: python, json

I wrote a function to validate Json objects in Python. Here is the code snippet:

```
def is_json(myjson):
    """
    Check whether a string is a json object.
    :param myjson: the string to check
    :return: True/False
    """
    try:
        json_object = json.loads(myjson)
    except ValueError, e:
        return False
    return True
```

However, I happened to find that it allows digit string. For instance,

```
is_json("123") # return True
is_json("-123") # return True
is_json("0123") # return False
is_json(" 123") # return True
```

From my understanding, number should not be part of Json data. And I also confirmed it with some other [Json formatter tool](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). If it is true, why would `json.loads` permit digits strings?

Comment: whicg python version?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka Python 2.7.12

Comment: @Kevin yes python appears to use RFC 7159  hence this is correct. https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: @Kevin, I think you are right. "The JSON format is specified by RFC 7159 and by ECMA-404." quoted from https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: `is_json(" 123") # return False` I ran your code, and this returns True (as it should)

Comment: @njzk2 verified. It is a mistake. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Python's [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module supports JSON specified by RFC 7159:

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), specified by RFC 7159 (which obsoletes RFC 4627)

Playing around with the validator you linked, "123" is invalid in 4627, but valid in 7159.

Comparing the two RFCs, it looks like the definition of what comprises valid JSON text became more broad. In 4627:

> `JSON-text = object / array`

And in 7159:

> `JSON-text = ws value ws`

(ws meaning "optional whitespace")

So originally you could only have an object or an array, but now you can have a value, which is "an object, array, number, or string, or one of the [...] names: false null true".

The `json` module documentation discusses the difference further:

> The old version of JSON specified by the obsolete RFC 4627 required that the top-level value of a JSON text must be either a JSON object or array (Python dict or list), and could not be a JSON null, boolean, number, or string value. RFC 7159 removed that restriction, and this module does not and has never implemented that restriction in either its serializer or its deserializer.

Comment: What if I want my function adhere to RFC 4627 cos I want to exclude numbers in the validator function?

Comment: @this-vidor, whoops, I thought a "value" was synonymous with "a valid standalone JSON document" but really it's `JSON-text`. Edited.

Comment: @Theresa, it doesn't look like there's any easy way to make a strict RFC 4627-compliant parser using just the builtin modules. In principle you could write your own parser (perhaps using Lex/Yacc/Flex/Bison), but that's a very "batteries not included" approach (and I'm not even sure how those tools integrate with Python, if at all).

Comment: Re: Not easy to comply strictly to RFC 4627 - Maybe I'm reading the RFC wrong, but it seems to me you could simply check whether the result (i.e. `json_object` in OP's example) was a Python `dict` or `list` (JSON object or array), and if not, then reject. Also, RFC 4627 has the following passage: *A JSON parser MUST accept all texts that conform to the JSON grammar. A JSON parser MAY accept non-JSON forms or extensions.* Thus, a parser that complies with RFC 7159 is, by that provision in RFC 4627, also a parser that complies with RFC 4627 (with extensions), isn't it?

Comment: `JSON-text = ws value ws` doesn't that conflict with the OP's result: `is_json(" 123") # return False`?

Comment: @njzk2: Yes, if the OP's code was accurate, Python's `json` module would not have been RFC7159-compliant. Fortunately, the OP's code was incorrect. `import json; assert json.loads(" 123") == 123` works fine for me in Python 2.7.10.

Comment: @Quuxplusone indeed!

Comment: I heard multiple times now that, while RFC7159 is the officially valid standard, most developers consider it inferior to RFC4627. Is there a proper source on the reasons for this?